# Using Highcharts in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, highcharts

I can't see any results using Highcharts in Django. I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/highcharts/highcharts.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/highcharts/modules/exporting.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },
                yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
                },
                legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
                }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
                }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
                }]
            });
            });
    </script>

    <div id='container' style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I've checked static path it's ok.

In settings.py i've already included 'highcharts' and 'jquery', then i've made python manage.py collectstatic and it is successfully collected.

Comment: Check the javascript console, any errors?

Comment: Have you any live demo, jquery is loaded correctly?